# Truncated names in DB2 tables list

Tags: command-line, db2

In the Windows command line when I ask for the table names in a certain schema the names are truncated:

```
db2 => list tables for schema SCH

Tabela/Exibição                 Esquema                         Tipo  Hora da cria
------------------------------- --------------- ----- --------------------------
TRUNCATED_TABLE_NAME_TRUNCATED> SCH             T     2017-01-29-11.11.11.111111
```

How to show the whole name without truncating or wrapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL:

```
select tabname,tabschema from syscat.tables where tabschema='SCH'
```

See the [catalog views](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011297.html) for details on more options.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the column with in the [DB2 CLP](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/comref/src/tpc/db2z_clpchangemaxcolumnwidthsyntax.html) with

```
CHANGE MAXCOLUMNWIDTH TO 80
```